# Activating python 3.6 virtual environment

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-3.6, layer

I am trying to create and export Shapely as an AWS Lambda Layer. It needs to be Python version 3.6 in order to work with my lambda code

To do so, I have tried the following

```
mkdir folder
cd folder
virtualenv --python=python3.6 myvenv 
source ./v-env/bin/activate
pip3 install shapely
deactivate
mkdir shapely
cd shapely 
cp -r ../v-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/* .
cd ..
zip -r shapely.zip shapely
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name shapely --zip-file fileb://shapely.zip --compatible-runtimes python3.6
```

However the `source ./v-env/bin/activate` returns the error `bash: ./v-env/bin/activate: No such file or directory`

How do I activate the virtual environment for python 3.6?

Comment: The name of the environment you created is `myvenv`, not `v-env`. Why do you then `deactivate` and attempt to copy stuff out of the env? That's not going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called your environment `myvenv` not `v-env`, so should be:

```sh
source ./myvenv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an environment called `myvenv`, which will create the folder `myvenv`, but are then trying to go to the folder `v-env`, which does not exist.

The steps should be:

```sh
mkdir folder
cd folder
virtualenv --python=python3.6 v-env 
source ./v-env/bin/activate
pip3 install shapely
deactivate
mkdir shapely
cd shapely 
cp -r ../v-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/* .
cd ..
zip -r shapely.zip shapely
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name shapely --zip-file fileb://shapely.zip --compatible-runtimes python3.6
```

Comment: Thanks! It has now successfully published and I've added it as a layer to my lambda function but I'm getting the error ```No module named 'shapely'``` - any idea what may have went wrong? As I got no error messages during publishing to AWS